# Derivation of the inequality

Tags: inequality

For positive integer k, for any $c>0$, does there exist $k_0>0$ that depends on c, such that:
$\sqrt{k}-c\leq\sqrt{k-1}$   ,$\forall k>k_0$

Comment: Write it $\underbrace{\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1}}_{f(k)} \le c$ and use the fact that $f(k)$ tends to $0$ when $k \to \infty$.

Comment: alternatively you can multiply both sides of $\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1} \le c$ by $\sqrt k+\sqrt{k-1}$ to get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1}} \le c$